# Ionic Framework : Ionic build fails while creating the project (v4.12.0)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, build, installation

I have `ionic` installed in my system. When i run `ionic run app tabs` it installs all the `npm` packages but then the prompt falls to

```
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

Then it fails with the prompt showing

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/l3g0b0y/code/greenlink/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/l3g0b0y/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/node" "/home/l3g0b0y/code/greenlink/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/l3g0b0y/code/greenlink/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.11.0 (node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

I have already tried removing `node_modules` and reinstall the packages. I tried reinstalling `ionic-cli` as well. Which doesn't work.

I'm using 
`node v12.0.0`
`npm v6.9.0`
`ionic v4.12.0`

Comment: Run `sudo npm rebuild node-sass` then `ionic run app tabs`

Comment: Indeed, the package is missing on github : `curl -I https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`. `npm rebuild` should not make any effect here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, the version `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node` is not available because you are using node `v12` and try to get unsupported version of `node-sass` for node v12.

The solution is to downgrade your node version to `v11` or upgrade your node-sass dependency to the latest.

If you (for visitors having the same issue w/ another library. Here, it is `ionic`) are using `node-sass` as a vendor library, downgrade to node v11 and notify the library developer team to the need for an update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved my problem :) I'm gonna raise this issue in github.

Comment: Going into node modules and fixing the node-sass dependencies worked for me. I used `npm ls node-sass` to find them all. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the node 11 to your dev-dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev node@11
```