# Docker Build cannot download https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node

Tags: docker, npm, node-sass

I've seen similiars posts, but none was using docker. I'm having an issue when doing a docker build:

When running the command:

docker build -t frontend -f frontendDockerfile .

I get:

```
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

Here is my frontendDockerFile:

```
FROM node

COPY /frontend/Express /Express

WORKDIR /Express

#RUN npm install && npm rebuild node-sass && npm run webpack
RUN npm install  && npm run webpack

CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

this particular package is a redirect, so if you're behind a firewall,  you will need to allow access to:

https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55893741/11506391), you get this error because you're using node v12.
This is true, as the latest docker tag also references node 12.

Switching to node 11 seems to resolve the problem.
Thus, you can try by modifying your base image :

```
FROM node:11

COPY /frontend/Express /Express

WORKDIR /Express
...
```